# Linking MainActivity and Overlay class

Tags: android, onclick, overlay, mapquest

I am currently doing a MapView with mapquest and require adding overlays to locations. Currently my MapView is working however the overlay does not appear. Any ideas as to how it can be solved? Also is it possible to create an onClick on the overlay to bring me to a ListView?? Thanks is advance!!
 
*my main activity*

```
public class QMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

protected MapView map;
AnnotationView annot;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutId());      
    init();       
    annot = new AnnotationView(map);


}

protected void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.setupMapView();    


}

protected void setupMapView() {
    // set the zoom level, center point and enable the default zoom controls 
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.getController().setZoom(16);
    map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(1.309503,103.777793));
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}

protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.main;
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

And **my Overlay class**

```
public class QPoiOverlay extends QMapsActivity{

protected void init() {
    super.init();
    setupMapView();

}

protected void addPoiOverlay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_marker);
    final DefaultItemizedOverlay poiOverlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(icon);

    OverlayItem loc1 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (1.308763,103.777321), "area","area");
    poiOverlay.addItem(loc1);
    OverlayItem loc2 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (1.309498,103.777101), "area","area");
    poiOverlay.addItem(loc2);
    OverlayItem loc3 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (1.311531,103.778318), "area","area");
    poiOverlay.addItem(loc3);
    OverlayItem loc4 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (1.308071,103.77841), "area","area");
    poiOverlay.addItem(loc4);

    poiOverlay.setOnFocusChangeListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChanged(ItemizedOverlay Overlay, OverlayItem newFocus) {
            // when focused item changes, recenter map and show info
            map.getController().animateTo(newFocus.getPoint());
            Toast.makeText(map.getContext().getApplicationContext(), newFocus.getTitle() + ": " + 
                    newFocus.getSnippet(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int lastTouchedIndex = poiOverlay.getLastFocusedIndex();
            if(lastTouchedIndex>-1){
                OverlayItem tapped = poiOverlay.getItem(lastTouchedIndex);
                annot.showAnnotationView(tapped);

            }

        }           
    });

    map.getOverlays().add(poiOverlay);
    map.invalidate();

} 

}
```

Comment: Definitely [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) will help